# Widget Style - Icon Type

Tags: images, widgets, icon

I would like to use custom image instead icon from Icon Picker in Widget. Problem is, that icon has size about 70x70px, but if I choose image, and I upload it there, it is much more bigger, even tough I use smaller image.

Icon

[image]

large image

[image]

small image

[image]

Could someone help me how to set size of the image? I want to have image of virus in front of caption "TEST" (like alternative with icon).

Edit:
This is widget (FT: Service) which I have mentioned about:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the icon picker widget?  Is that part of some theme or plugin?

Comment: @TonyDjukic I have added screenshots from widget settings. I am using Flash theme.